# calling a method from another function in JS (TypeError exception)

Tags: javascript

I guess it's really a newbie error, but I can't get it running.
I have an "calculator" object t, which contains a lot of function to calculate values. I need to use these functions from my "calculator" object to get some values in another function. 
I striped it down to the following, but I get an TypeError exceptio when I call the t.hello() method. Any ideas?

```
 var t = new T();
 two();

 function T() {
     function hello() {
         alert("hello");
     }
 }

 function two() {

     t.hello();

 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Cc4F/

Comment: Actually `hello` in your example is not a method, it is a local function defined inside other function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to return an object that contains the function:

```
function T() {
    return {
        'hello': function () {
            alert("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Or specifically define it as an function in `T`'s scope:

```
function T() {
    this.hello = function() {
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/93AqU/)

Comment: I see, thanks! But one additional. How do I call "hello" inside from T now?

Comment: @audio_developer: In the second example, you can use `this.hello()`, within `T`. You can't when using the first example.

Comment: thanks again. I tried exactly that before I asked, but did a typo for the call "this.hello(}" ... I guess this means I need a short break. :-) have a good day!

Comment: I discovered another question: Is this a good style to call hello from an inner function with that?  http://jsfiddle.net/9H4JM/

Comment: @audio_developer: Yea, that works too. That way, you can create private functions.

Comment: good to know, thanks. I have a function in a function in my object, linke in the example, and I need to access them - but I didn't know if this "that" workaround is considers a dirty hack or something.

Comment: The `that` is often used for just... that :P

Answer (score 1):

function `hello` is in local scope of `T`.

define `T` like this.

```
function T() {
     this.hello = function() {
         alert("hello");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var t = new T();
two();
function T() {
     this.hello = function () {
         alert("hello");
     }
 }    
 function two() {    
     t.hello();    
 }
```

see this : http://jsfiddle.net/4Cc4F/2/